# Applying a CSS class on click to a list item?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm having an issue getting a CSS class to be applied to a list item on click. It seems to work with the first item in the list, but not the other ones.

Here is the HTML for one of the lists.

```
 <div class="card-action">
                        <h5 id='current-list'>Current Set List</h5>
                        <h6 id="set-id-1" class="center">Set #1</h6>
                        <hr>
                        <ul class='collection set-1' id="set-1">
                           <li class="collection-item song-item">
                               Live Wire (AC/DC)
                           </li>
                           <li class="collection-item song-item">
                            Whole Lotta Rosie (AC/DC)
                            <li class="collection-item song-item">
                               Sin City (AC/DC)
                            </li>
                            <li class="collection-item song-item">
                               Jailbreak (AC/DC)
                             </li>
                             <li class="collection-item song-item">
                                The Zoo (Scorpions)
                             </li>
                             <li class="collection-item song-item">
                                Immigrant Song (Led Zeppelin)
                             </li>
                             <li class="collection-item song-item">
                                Breaking The Chains (Dokken)
                             </li>
                             <li class="collection-item song-item">
                               Neon Knights (Black Sabbath)
                             </li>
                             <li class="collection-item song-item">
                                Paranoid (Black Sabbath)
                             </li>
                             <li class="collection-item song-item">
                                Metal Gods (Judas Priest)
                             </li>
                             <li class="collection-item song-item">
                                Breaking The Law (Judas Priest)
                             </li>
                             <li class="collection-item song-item">
                                Green Manalishi (Judas Priest)
                             </li>
                             <li class="collection-item song-item">
                                Diamonds & Rust (Judas Priest)
                             </li>
                        </ul>
```

Here is the JavaScript I'm trying to use

```
const songSelect = querySelector('li');

function changeColor() {
  songSelect.classList.add('song-selection')
  console.log(songSelect)
}
songSelect.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

Here is the CSS class

```
.song-selection {
    background-color: gray !important;
    color: red !important
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an event listener to every single list item is considered to be bad practice. Instead you can use one click event to handle all your list items.

Instead do something like this

```
const songSelects = document.getElementById('set-1'); // This is your UL element

function changeColor(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('song-selection');
}

songSelects.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

This example will add an event listener to your UL element which will capture every clicked on list item within the list. You can access the actual item that has been clicked on through the event object, specifically its `target` property. This will then add your class to the individual list item that was clicked.

This process is called event delgation and if you'd like, you can read more about it here https://javascript.info/event-delegation

More detail about why you should use event delgation rather than adding a listener to every item. https://ehsangazar.com/optimizing-javascript-event-listeners-for-performance-e28406ad406c

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'm not the guy asking the question, but I did provide an answer adding an eventListener to each `li` tag. I'm still relatively new to JavaScript, so can you explain why it's bad practice? Thank you!!

EDIT: I just read that entire article that you posted. Thank you!

Comment: @kvncnls as far as why it's bad practice, it would require much more space than is available here, but I'll provide you with this blog post that covers it in pretty good detail and provides some of the reasons why you wouldn't want to have an event listener for every single item. https://ehsangazar.com/optimizing-javascript-event-listeners-for-performance-e28406ad406c

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! I've updated my answer to include this additional blog post as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll` to obtain all of the elements and then loop over them to add all the event listeners.

```
const songSelects = document.querySelectorAll('li');
function changeColor() {
  this.classList.add('song-selection')
  console.log(this)
}
songSelects.forEach(songSelect=>songSelect.addEventListener('click', changeColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** On second thought, Chris has a better answer. My method has us adding `eventListeners` to each `li` tag, which can be cumbersome in the long-run. His method has us add an `eventListener` to the common parent of the `li` tags. - Always humbled by the people in StackOverflow. :D

---

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll` on your `li` tags to select all of your `li` tags.

Then you need to use `forEach()` on the array holding these `li` tags to loop over them and give them an `eventListener`. Once you've added an `eventListener` on each `li` tag, you can give them the `changeColor` function that you created.

However, we need to modify that function a bit. I used `this.classList.add("song-selection");` to target the selected `li` tag.

You can see my working code below. Hopefully it helps!

```js
const songs = document.querySelectorAll("li");

songs.forEach((song) => {
  song.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
});

function changeColor() {
  this.classList.add("song-selection");
  console.log(this);
}
```

```css
.song-selection {
  background-color: gray !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-action">
    <h5 id='current-list'>Current Set List</h5>
    <h6 id="set-id-1" class="center">Set #1</h6>
    <hr>
    <ul class='collection set-1' id="set-1">
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Live Wire (AC/DC)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Whole Lotta Rosie (AC/DC)
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Sin City (AC/DC)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Jailbreak (AC/DC)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        The Zoo (Scorpions)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Immigrant Song (Led Zeppelin)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Breaking The Chains (Dokken)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Neon Knights (Black Sabbath)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Paranoid (Black Sabbath)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Metal Gods (Judas Priest)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Breaking The Law (Judas Priest)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Green Manalishi (Judas Priest)
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item song-item">
        Diamonds & Rust (Judas Priest)
      </li>
    </ul>
```